# Tchebychev coordinates on hyperbolic space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Is there any known example of an open subset $U\subset\mathbb{H}^n$ with infinite volume admitting (global) Tchebychev coordinates for $n\geq3$?

Comment: Here's an old question that came to mind though I'm not sure if it helps https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91429/chebyshev-net-in-3d

Comment: What's your definition of Tschebyshev coordinates?

Comment: @DeaneYang: By Tschebyshev coordinates I mean a coordinate system whose coordinate vector fields have all unit length everywhere